# Functions binded to Output directive not working as intended

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have one parent component (**parent-component**) and three child component of the same type (**camera-component**).

The child component has an *EventEmitter* (**onTakePhoto**) and every child component has his own output function binded in the parent component:

**Parent.html:**

```
<parent-component>
    ...
    <camera-component  (onTakePhoto)="function1"></camera-component>
    <camera-component  (onTakePhoto)="function2"></camera-component>
    <camera-component  (onTakePhoto)="function3></camera-component>
    ...
</parent-component>
```

**Child.html (camera-component.html)**

```
<label for="file-upload"
        class="label">
       
        <mat-icon id="camera-icon"class="mat-icon">photo_camera</mat-icon>
            
</label>

<input id="file-upload"
        type="file"
        capture="camera"
        accept="image/*"
        hidden="true"
        (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

**Child.ts (camera-component.ts)**

```
export class CameraComponent {

  @Output() public onTakePhoto: EventEmitter<Promise<string>> = new EventEmitter();

  fileReader: FileReader;

  constructor(private imageCompresser: NgxImageCompressService) {
    this.fileReader = new FileReader();
  }

  public onFileChange(fileEvent: any) {

    if (fileEvent.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = fileEvent.target.files[0];
      this.compressFile(file);
      fileEvent.target.value = null;

    }
  }

  private compressFile(file: any) {

    this.fileReader.onload = () => {
      this.onTakePhoto.emit(
        this.imageCompresser.compressFile(changeDpiDataUrl(this.fileReader.result.toString(), 72),
          DOC_ORIENTATION.Up, 100, 90)
      );
    }
    this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

But when I try to launch the **onTakePhoto** event, It does not matter which child component launches the event. "Function1" will always be called.

Each child component has its own instance of event emitter?

Thanks in advance :)

**[EDIT]**

I have recreated the problem in StackBlitz and it works fine:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwddaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: Don't see a problem in the code. Can you share a stackblitz?

Comment: This may not help, but try removing the `id` attribute from your `input`, because you're currently adding multiple elements with the same idea to the DOM.

Comment: Hi, @WillAlexander,

The id's are not written in the code. I added them to represent the different elements of the same type of component.

Comment: @DRASHTIDOBARIYA sure

Comment: You have ids on the `input` tags though, that's where there could be an issue.

Comment: Hey @WillAlexander, you were right! I was using a laber for the input and the three instances were sharing the same label. I will post the fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[FIX]**

So, as @WillAlexander stated:

The child component (camera-component.ts) was sharing the same input and label id for all three instances.

Every time the child event was triggered from any instance of the child component type, the first function assigned to that type of component was fired. (My case was "function1" because was the first function binded to the Output directive).

**Now, A GUID is created for every instance and it's assigned to the label and input id:**

**Child.ts (camera-component.ts)**

```
export class CameraComponent {

  ...

  public id;

  constructor(private imageCompresser: NgxImageCompressService) {
    ...

    this.id = Guid.create().toString();
  }
```

**Child.html (camera-component.html)**

```
<label for="file-upload{{id}}"
        class="label">
       
        <mat-icon id="camera-icon"class="mat-icon">photo_camera</mat-icon>
            
</label>

<input id="file-upload{{id}}"
        type="file"
        capture="camera"
        accept="image/*"
        hidden="true"
        (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```